# Ionic variable loss

Tags: javascript, local-storage, ionic4

I'm writing an app that allow my RPI to connect to the internet via bluetooth
This part works, but i'm trying to store the ID of my RPI on the phone,
The problem is that my variable loses their value (null)

Here's the code

```
              timeout(10000).then( () => {
              this.ble.read(
                this.deviceID,
                this.uuidConfig.serviceUUID,
                this.uuidConfig.readStatusUUID,
              ).then( (data) => {
                  const status = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(data));
                  if (this.ble.isConnected) {
                    if(status.ID !== undefined){
                      this.presentToast("Success !");
                      this.storage.get('SpectR').then(spectrID => {
                     // At this exact location, status.ID is null, I don't get whyy
                        if (spectrID === null){
                          let arrId = status.ID.split()
                          this.storage.set('SpectR', arrId ).then(r => console.log('done') )
                        }
                        else{
                          spectrID.push(status.ID)
                          this.storage.set('SpectR', spectrID ).then(r => console.log('done') )
                        }
                      })
                      this.navCtrl.back()
                    } else {
                      this.presentToast("Wrong password :/")
                    }
                  } else if (!this.ble.isConnected) {
                    this.presentToast("Something went wrong :/")
                  }
                }
              )
            }
          )
```

Do you have any idea?
Before adding the storage part, the value never got overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Debug, I can't comment on questions yet... Respond with the value of status

```
timeout(10000).then(() => {
    this.ble.read(
        this.deviceID,
        this.uuidConfig.serviceUUID,
        this.uuidConfig.readStatusUUID,
    ).then((data) => {
        const status = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(data));
        // DEBUG START
        // DEBUG START
        // DEBUG START
        console.info('DEBUG START')
        console.log({ status })
        console.info('DEBUG END')
        // DEBUG END
        // DEBUG END
        // DEBUG END
        if (this.ble.isConnected) {
            if (status.ID !== undefined) {
                this.presentToast("Success !");
                this.storage.get('SpectR').then(spectrID => {
                    // At this exact location, status.ID is null, I don't get whyy
                    if (spectrID === null) {
                        let arrId = status.ID.split()
                        this.storage.set('SpectR', arrId).then(r => console.log('done'))
                    }
                    else {
                        spectrID.push(status.ID)
                        this.storage.set('SpectR', spectrID).then(r => console.log('done'))
                    }
                })
                this.navCtrl.back()
            } else {
                this.presentToast("Wrong password :/")
            }
        } else if (!this.ble.isConnected) {
            this.presentToast("Something went wrong :/")
        }
    }
    )
}
)
```

Comment: Using this with the chrome://inspect/#devices debugging system showed me that the problem isn't on the code side, but on the device i'm communcating with , the ID was empty from the get go, thanks you !